# ng click of button inside datatable column dont work

Tags: angularjs

I'm facing a problem with a column of my datatable where I have for some rows a button to edit something. So to  do this I create this button `<button ng-click="setActiveTab()">SetActiveTab</button>';` inside the columns of my datatableOptions and when I click on the button an alert should pop up

```
controllerScope.datatableOptions = {
    ajax: {
        url: '/api/organizations/' + $rootScope.user.organization_id + '/devices',
        dataSrc: '',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", AuthService.authToken());
        }
    },
    columns: [{
            "data": null,
            "orderable": true,
            "type": "boolean-sort-asc",
            "render": function (data) {
                if (data.data.status) {
                    return '<span class="badge bg-success" data-sort="1" style="width:21px;"> </span>';
                } else {
                    return '<span class="badge bg-danger" data-sort="0" style="width:21px;"> </span>';
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "data": null,
            "orderable": false,
            "render": function (data) {
                //return '<a ui-sref="app.dashboarddevice({id:\"' + data.id + '\"})">' + data.data.name + '</a>';
                return '<a class="state-link" data-state-id="' + data.id + '">' + data.data.name + '</a>';
            }
        },
        {
            "data": "data.sn",
            "defaultContent": ""
        },
        {
            "data": "modified_date",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
                return $filter('date')(row.modified_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
            }
        },
        {
            "data": "data.last_seen",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
                return $filter('date')(row.data.last_seen, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
            }
        },
        {
            "data": "model",
            "defaultContent": ""
        },
        {
            "data": "network_data.name",
            "defaultContent": ""
        },
        {
            "data": "data.clients",
            "defaultContent": ""
        },
        {
            "data": null,
            "orderable": false,
            "render": function (data) {
                var icon = "";
                if (data.data.consumptions_alert != undefined && data.data.consumptions_alert == true) {
                    //return icon = '<center><a class="state-link" data-state-id="' + data.id + '"><i style="color:#ff0000; width:21px; height:21px" title="Consumptions threshold exceed" class="fa fa-warning"></i></a></center>';
                    icon += '<a class="state-link" data-state-id="' + data.id + '" ng-click="setActiveTab(\'consumptions\')"><i style="color:#ff0000; width:21px; height:21px" title="Consumptions threshold exceed" class="fa fa-warning"></i></a>';
                }
                if (data.data.cpuLoad_alert == true || data.data.disk_alert == true || data.data.ram_alert == true || data.data.temperatures_alert == true) {
                    icon += '<button ng-click="setActiveTab()">SetActiveTab</button>';
                }
                icon = "<center>" + icon + "</center>";
                return icon;
            }
        },
    ],
    lengthMenu: [25, 50, 100, 150],
    order: [
        [0, 'desc']
    ]

};
};

$scope.setActiveTab = function () {
    alert("clicked set");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use JsFiddle link as provided. you have to include $windows in your controller
https://jsfiddle.net/Prasanna15/wL9v8nj9/

```
app.controller('ctrlName', function($scope, $windows){
//code
})
```

Comment: I'm doing that and still don't work.. If I make a plunker its okay but if I click in my button inside datatablpe theb utton dont open. I dont understand

Comment: It seems when you are rendering html page, it is unable to find respected controller. it's better to define your controller in app.routes. e.g `.when('/user',{
            templateUrl: 'views/users.html',
            controller: 'yourControllerName',controllerAs:'controllerAliseName'
        })`

Comment: Is everything defined in my routes file, but insstead of when I use state

Comment: share your routes file

Comment: Can we discuss in chat please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153884/discussion-between-prasanna-sasne-and-andre-bastos).